# Mutable shared flow failed to collect emitted values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-sharedflow

I started on building Apps using Android Compose and am learning Kotlin's coroutine and stuff. Below are the samples of code that I have written for an app, where I tried to use MutableSharedFlow **emit** and **collectLatest** for updating UI.
[Init Method of ViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKWMw.png)

```
init {
    try {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = state.value.copy(
                isSearchStarted = true
            )
            userCredRepository.getCred().also {security ->
                if (security?.authToken.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    println("RECEIVED NULL TOKEN")
                    delay(100)
                    _eventFlow.emit(LoginSignUpEvent.ErrorEvent("Please Login to continue", ""))
                    _state.value = state.value.copy(
                        isSearchStarted = false
                    )
                }else{
                    delay(100)
                    _eventFlow.emit(LoginSignUpEvent.SuccessEventLogIn("Subscribing"))
                }

            }
        }
    }catch (ex: CancellationException){
        println(ex.message)
    }catch (ex: Exception){
       println(ex.message)
    }
}
```

This is the view modal for the Login SingUp screen. Here **userCredRepository** communicates with sqlite database, and fetches the token on the app startup.

[Login SignUp Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgkg9.png)

```
 LaunchedEffect(true) {
    loginSignUpViewModal.eventFlow.collectLatest { event ->
        when (event) {
            is LoginSignUpEvent.ErrorEvent -> {
                state.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    message = event.message!!,
                    actionLabel = event.actionMessage
                )
            }
            is LoginSignUpEvent.SuccessEventSignUp -> {
                state.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    message = event.message!!,
                    actionLabel = event.actionMessage
                )
            }
            is LoginSignUpEvent.SuccessEventLogIn -> {
                navController.popBackStack()
                navController.navigate(NotesScreen.HomeScreen.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is sample code of Login Sign Up Screen where I listen to MutableSharedFlow's emitted values. This is the first screen that is displayed when the app runs ,and navigates to another screen if token is present.
So the issue here is that the emitted values are not caught until I add **dely(100)** (as in the first code sample line 10 & 16 from start) before emitting values in the ViewModal.
I have attached the link to the project.[Link to project](https://github.com/sachetwasti1997/notes-app)

Below is the updated code using **Channel** instead of Mutable shared flow, here it works well.

```
private val _eventFlow = Channel<LoginSignUpEvent>()
val eventFlow = _eventFlow.receiveAsFlow()

val toggleLoginSignupScreen = mutableStateOf(false)
var passwordVisibility = mutableStateOf(false)

init {
    try {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = state.value.copy(
                isSearchStarted = true
            )
            userCredRepository.getCred().also {security ->
                if (security?.authToken.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    _eventFlow.send(LoginSignUpEvent.ErrorEvent("Please Login to continue", ""))
                    _state.value = state.value.copy(
                        isSearchStarted = false
                    )
                }else{
                    _state.value = state.value.copy(
                        isSearchStarted = false,
                    )
                    _eventFlow.send(LoginSignUpEvent.SuccessEventLogIn("Subscribing"))
                }

            }
        }
    }catch (ex: CancellationException){
        println(ex.message)
    }catch (ex: Exception){
       println(ex.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using `collectLatest`? instead of `collect`?

Comment: Hi @kingston collect will collect every value , and collectLatest will stop current work to collect latest value, but using collect doesn't solve it. I had tried that.

Comment: If `getCred` does not suspend, then it's expected behaviour: `LaunchedEffect` is getting launched after `viewModelScope.launch`, so at time of `_eventFlow.emit`, `collectLatest` has not yet being run. Try adding logs to check this theory

Comment: Check this video. This info might help. https://youtu.be/QNrNKPKe5oc

Comment: I have same issue. @PhilDukhov then how should we run api calls on just entering to the creen? Given that result should be prosessed as a single event, not as state